Installing LVP floor
If it is not okay to install cabinets on a floating LVP floor, why is it okay to install a heavy refrigerator on top of it?  We are putting down flooring in a 264 sq ft studio with a kitchen 6’6” wide and 11’6” long.  There will only be 6’3” of base cabinet and have read not to put the flooring under because it needs to float but it is okay under the refrigerator. How does it float under there?  Thanks.

I do not know about the floating, but cabinets are never moved, so I like to save the money by not putting nice flooring under them.  Fridges/stoves should be moved once in a blue moon to clean under them, so it makes sense if there is not a lip.

I hear you Cindy G.
I can tell you I have done the LVP both ways. I find it easier to lay the floor in the entire room and then instal the cabinets. There is also a misunderstanding of what a "floating " floor is. "Floating" simply means the floor is not attached to whatever is under it. This should not be confused with the need for the floor to expand and contract. That is a product of the composition of the floor and not the definition of "floating".
That said;
I have done the flooring then cabinets over in 3 of my 5 rentals and a number of other homes. I have done the cabinets and then the flooring in others.
I have found no difference in flooring performance between the 2 methods. This has been over about a 5 year period.  One manufacturer had recommended that the flooring be glued down where cabinets would be going. I did that only in that one instance where it was recommended.  Otherwise it's flooring then cabinets.
There will be the argument of voiding the warranty. That is true. However in over 50 years of doing home building and remodeling, I have never had or heard of an instance of someone making a claim over their flooring with the exception of hardwood or engineered wood flooring. That type of flooring has different issues. ( Don't get me started on that stuff)
I do remove baseboards before doing the flooring. Then after everything is done I caulk the baseboard to the flooring and along the toe kicks of the cabinets.  This to seal any spilled water and prevent it from getting under the flooring. That has proved to be valuable, as after hurricane Milton I had a property that lost part of a roof, but the rain that came in just sat on the waterproof flooring and caused no other damage.

If you caulk the baseboards and toe kicks doesn't that defeat the "floating" nature?

@Huesmann, I would not caulk if using a laminated flooring with a wood core. However LVP has a solid core that is far more stable and the movement of the floor is very minor. ( LVP does not need to acclimate like laminate.) Never had an issue with caulking the floor. It has saved issues from water, so I will continue.

Thank you for your answer to my question!  And including your experience is invaluable
